# cellForRowAtIndex called automatically on UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I implemented `UIRefreshControl` in `UITableView` with `valueChange` event.
When I pull it down, it calls `cellForRowAtIndex` automatically without calling `numberOfRowsInSection`.
Even I am not calling `tableView.reload()`

Answer (score 4):

its because of when you pull down some tableview *bottom cell are hide* and when you release it the hidden cell again show so for these cells tableview has to call cellForRowAtIndex for this cell. for testing you can nslog the indexpath.row

Answer (score 0):

Sumit,

In UIRefresh Control you have to scroll your table view cells  downward. In that case the cells on the bottom hides.

As you also know that we table view has cell reusable property. Which cause the removal as well as the addition of cells.

Thats why when the table scrolls down, few cells hide, then the reusable property of table view deletes the cell.

**This is the reason, cellForRowAtIndex called automatically.**